# Can't install Tensrflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I'm a beginner in Deep Learning and NLP stream. I was trying to install Tensorflow but it is giving me an error. Can anyone please help me how to solve this?
[This is the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm2rk.png)

I was watchig an YouTube video for Toxic Comment Classification and thought should try that out for better practice. After creating an enviroment for the file I triedd to install Tensorflow but it threw this error. I updated my Anaconda, Updated python to 3.11 and pip to 22.3 but still it is not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!!

Have you tried installing each package indivually?

Like this

```
pip install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

And so on

Answer (score 0):

I ran your CLI commands from the picture separately as-well.
The error you are getting is from tensorflow-gpu command.
I've found a link for you, from where you can learn about it. [[link]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EmZZsy7Ym-4)